# Data standardization using ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tf.keras, image-preprocessing

I have a folder that is called ‘train’, which is divided into 8 sub folders with each sub folder contains the data ( images )of one class ( and hence my dataset is a multi class one with 8 classes) . Now I have the following questions :

1. I need to do standardization feature-wise and therefore I need to use `datagen.fit( xtrain )` and I don’t know how to create x
   _train with all of my data, which are separated in different folders as I haven’t work with images before with python . Note I have enough memory to store all the data at once.
2. Since I have 8 classes do the stats be calculated on each class separately , if so how could I do that using the .fit( x_train) ?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below sample code snippets to resolve your query.(I have used 20 images dataset of two classes)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

PATH ="/train/"   #path to your train directory which contains 8 subfolders

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(PATH, target_size=(50, 50), batch_size=5, class_mode='binary')  #class_mode='categorical'
```

Output:

```
Found 20 images belonging to 2 classes.
```

After defining and compiling the model, fit this dataset to the model.

```
num_classes = 2   # you can define num_classes = 8

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=2,epochs=5)  # you can define steps_per_epoch=(number of images/batch_size),epochs
```

Please refer this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification#download_and_explore_the_dataset) for more detials.